# Fetch users groups with tastypie /api/v1/user

Tags: django, api, tastypie

With django/tastypie, I'm calling /api/v1/user, and would like the names of the groups assigned to that user returned.

Any idea how this could be done? I tried using various dehydrate methods, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add this line to UserResource...

```
groups = fields.ManyToManyField(GroupResource, 'groups', null=True, full=True)
```

Comment: where is this GroupResource located ??

Comment: `from group.api import GroupResource`

Comment: then create a group.api class: `class GroupResource(ModelResource)`